# unable to rectify error in database updation using php

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to update my database with php and for that I have written the following query :

```
$query = " UPDATE users SET username = '$username' , password = '$password' WHERE id = $id ";
```

and the **error** is shown as :

> *You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '' at line 1*

can you please help..

Comment: are any of the variables empty? Check for that. Also please use prepared statements.

Comment: Either $username or $password is blank

Comment: @maddy23285: not `username` nor `password`. Both can be blank. You can update to empty string.

Comment: Please use prepared and parameterized queries to avoid sql injection hacks.

Comment: @SAS: `$id` doesn't exists.

Answer (score 0):

“syntax to use near ‘something’” shows the first few characters after the last part of the query that MySQL could parse.  When ‘something’ is a zero-length string like in this case, it means the query ended before it was complete. That points to `$id` being an empty string.

You didn’t ask for comments on whether your query has other severe problems that will certainly lead to cybercreeps pwning your web site, so I won’t offer any such comments. :-)

Comment: Web sites, even recently configured ones that don’t appear in search engine listings, get hundreds of requests per day from maliciously crafted scripts trying to find vulnerabilities. Some people call the public internet the *dirty wire*. That is an accurate name for it. Be careful.